# PHP Individual Application Level Error Logging

Tags: php, apache, logging, iis

Using IIS 8.8 and PHP

How can I log application errors to a file in IIS? I have it working in my localhost XAMPP environment but doesn't seem to work when I migrate to an IIS server, which I have little experience in.

In my application I have a file `config.php`, it's included on each page in my application and it contains the following;

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_app\logs\err_log'); 
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
?>
```

However nothing is being logged in the `err_log` - do I have to change something else in the IIS settings?

I will have multiple applications on this server and would like to configure separate application log files for each of them, e.g.

- C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_app\logs\err_log
- C:\inetpub\wwwroot\another_app\logs\err_log
- C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yet_another_app\logs\err_log

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy an application to IIS on a Windows server, IIS can record errors related to http request responses, such as error status codes and detailed error messages. The errors within your php application (errors during application runtime) require you to configure through the php code or configuration file to allow the application to output error information to the specified file, and IIS cannot record the internal errors of the application.

So if you use config.php file to configure log file which is used to record http error, it won't work because only web.config file can configure IIS. If it just used to record error in application, you need to check php code or get help on php-related forums.

There are two ways to record error in IIS.

1. In [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/iis-logging) module, you can configure the log folder, log record format, log event destination, log file rollover. The final log file will record the time of receiving the request, the ip of the request, the url of the request, the status code and the status subcode, etc.
2. In [fail request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) module, you can record the whole process of request and response in detailed.When the request enters iis, which module it entered, how the module processed the request and the processing result will be recorded. It is of great help in troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. So basically it's not possible using my current configuration. I find it amazing that there's no way of recording PHP errors in IIS, I guess I should have done my research and used Apache instead, i'll know for next time!